# help tool tips are not showing in VF Pages in Lightning Experience but showing in Classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a VfPage, we have help tool tips to some fields, these tool tips are showing in Classic view, when i switched to lightning by changing the URL to /one.one/app i am able to see all the tool tips here we don't have any problem.
But when i switched to lightning experience by clicking the 'Switch to Lightning Experience' Unable to see the Tool tips in VF Pages, I am wondered with the bug.
is this a Limitation in Lightning or any other reason behind this.
Please Let me know Friends, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I asked the same question here [Visualforce field help icon/text not rendered in Lightning Experience?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151484/visualforce-field-help-icon-text-not-rendered-in-lightning-experience) and posted it on the ideas foum under [Help text on hover for Visualforce inside Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4aDQAS). Unknown when/if it will be addressed.

Comment: I voted for your Idea and finally  it is a limitation we have in Lightning experience right

Comment: Yeah presumably there was something awkward about it so it was dropped as a feature which is a pity and at the moment there is no commitment from Salesforce to bring it back.